# Asp.net MVC - How to upload files without pressing send button? Automatically uploaded once selected the files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

> How can i make the upload file action automatically once the files selected. means that the action will go to **index** action without pressing any button? Thanks in advance..

[image]

> View

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="faxnumber" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Select File:</label>
                <input type="file" name="files" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="btnSubmit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        @ViewBag.Message
    </table>
</form>
```

> javascript

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("file").onchange = function () {
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }
</script>
```

> Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
  //some code here
}
```

**UPDATE**

After selected files, the files will auto uploaded and the details will be stored in object name `Document` then back to the view with fail or success message. Then when I hit **Send** button all details will pass to the **Send** action in controller. How can I manage this process? The upload part is done already..but now I'm stuck in how can I **send** all the details to the next action in controller.

```
 public class Document
  {
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public byte[] Binary { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
  }
```

> SendController

```
public ActionResult Send(Document doc)
    {
      //some code here
    }
```

Comment: In your javascript, you use `getElementById("form")`, but your form tag doesn't have the `id` attribute set, which is why your code does not work.

Comment: @Wawa try to use jquery, it is much cleaner

Comment: @BradleyMoorfield ya I miss that form id, but still not working after add form id.
`<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Do you want to take a look at 3rd party tools? It's easier

Comment: @User2012384 ya sure. please share..thanks.

Comment: What is your file type doc or image or video?

Comment: In the previous projects, I used QQ File upload which suits my needs.

Comment: @DhakaPariBahan the file type could be .doc or image. the upload part is ok already, now im stuck again. I updates my question above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work fine if you change your submit button name value to anything other than "**submit**".

```
 <input type="submit" name="notsubmit" value="Send" id="btnSubmit" />
```

This is an interesting behavior ! I really do not know why it does not submit when the name attribute value is `"submit"`. I will update the answer when i get any more info.

Comment: awesome! thanks for help.. :) @Shyju

Comment: I did update my question above..